# Cannot redeclare class error in Laravel but works fine in native php

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Alchemy API for filter out some data. Everything works fine in the native code. But when i used it in my Laravel Controller it throws Cannot redeclare class. `My controller,alchemyapi.php and example.php` are in the same directory. Here is how i include `alchemyapi.php` in native code

```
<?php   

require_once 'alchemyapi.php';
$alchemyapi = new AlchemyAPI("MY API KEY"); ?>
```

But when i include it in the controller it throws my the error. is there something i am missing ?

```
require_once 'alchemyapi.php';
$alchemyapi = new AlchemyAPI("MY API KEY");
```

The native code(`example.php`) works well without any issue. But in laravel controller it throws a error saying `Cannot redeclare class AlchemyAPI
in alchemyapi.php line 20`

Comment: Where is alchemyapi.php in the project, could you post your composer.json?

Comment: @RichardVanbergen alchemyapi.php is in `App\Http\Controllers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `require_once` use `namespace` in your `alchemyapi.php` and then use `use` for same `namespace` in your `MyController`

**alchemyapi.php**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controller;
    class AlchemyApi {
        //your code
    }
```

**MyController.php**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controller;
    use App\Http\Controller\AlchemyApi;
    class MyController {
        $alchemy = new AlchemyApi("Your_api_key");
    }
```

Comment: Both are in same Directory. namespace App\Http\Controllers. are used in both files but still the issue exists.

Comment: instead of using `require_once` use `use \App\Http\Controllers\alchemyapi.php`

Comment: it just throws a error and didnt work . `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'` and my code is `use App\Http\Controllers\alchemyapi.php;`

Comment: sorry my mistake you have to use class name not file name i.e. `use \App\Http\Controller\AlchemyAPI;`

Comment: you might have to do a `composer update` to reload class mapping

Comment: it worked. But another issue is , it says undefined variable $alchemyapi. Here is my shared code [link](https://codeshare.io/amq91a). See line number 59.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131901/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-cybersupernova).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what I think is happening is that `alchemyapi.php` is somehow already being included by the composer autoloader.

Try this.

1. Create the directory `lib` in the root of your project.
2. **Move** alchemiapi.php into lib.
3. Under the "autoload" section in your `composer.json` add the following code. Make sure the JSON is valid:

   ```
   "files": [
       "lib/alchemyapi.php",
   ],
   ```
4. Run `composer dump-autoload`. If it errors, your `composer.json` is invalid or you haven't put the file in the correct place.
5. **Delete** `require_once 'alchemyapi.php';` from your controller.

When dealing with composer, this is how you deal with classes in the global namespace. After running composer it scan those directories in `app` for PSR-4 classes.

I can't be sure but I think that composer is looking for it and you are also manually requiring it. That would explain why PHP thinks you are redeclaring the class.